# Sound clip in flash not playing properly

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm working on an interactive flash software which consist of playing audio and showing slideshows, for each slideshow there is a corresponding sound clip.

To organize the sound so I can easily pause and play it, I make the sound as movie clips and put them on one layer. When there is a slide change, I put a keyframe that consist of the corresponding sound movie clip for the slide, and delete the previous sound movie clip from the stage.

However, when I do gotoAndPlay() to the beginning of slide 2 from slide 3, the sound for slide 1 started playing too. I'm confused since I have deleted the first sound movie clip just before the beginning of the slide 2.

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with Flash and put sounds directly into the timeline, they play until they finished as default.
So try to set the synchronisation mode to "Stream". This should help you. If not you can add your soundclips programmatically and control them with Actionscript.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually use the second method to solve my problem. Rather than putting the sound on the movie clip, I just load them externally using sound and soundchannel class, and its so easy to manage.